# Opening BizFx tool gives 403 Forbidden responses in Sitecore Commerce 9 on PaaS

Tags: sitecore-commerce, paas

We have followed documentation on how to install Sitecore Commerce 9 on PaaS. Done Bootstrapping and all post installation steps.

When trying to on open Business Tools from Sitecore Launchpad, we see indefinite loop during start and 3 403 Forbidden responses for these requests:

2x GET method - xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNavigationView()
GET method - xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/GetLanguagesView()

My user is Administrator.

Environment is HabitatAuthoring.

This is how it looks like - Indefinite loop:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to assign "Commerce Administrator" role to the user.

"Administrator" checkbox is not sufficient to access BizFX tools.

"Commerce Business User" is minimum role that needs to be assigned to access Business Tools.