# Opening BizFx tool gives 400 Bad Request responses with InvalidShop in Sitecore Commerce 9 on PaaS

Tags: sitecore-commerce, paas

We have followed documentation on how to install Sitecore Commerce 9 on PaaS. Done Bootstrapping and almost all post installation steps.

After fixing issues with [403 Forbidden exceptions](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/opening-bizfx-tool-gives-403-forbidden-responses-in-sitecore-commerce-9-on-paas) we tried to open Business Tools from Sitecore Launchpad. Unfortunately, we saw indefinite loop during start and 400 Bad Request responses for these requests:

> 2x GET method - xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/GetNavigationView() GET
>   method - xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/GetLanguagesView()

This was response code:

> "@odata.context":"https://xxxxxxxx-authoring.azurewebsites.net/Api/$metadata#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.CommandMessage","MessageDate":"2018-05-23T12:17:32.0106229Z","Code":"Error","Text":"Shop
>   'xxxxxxCommerceEngineStorefront' does not
>   exist.","CommerceTermKey":"InvalidShop"

Environment is HabitatAuthoring.

This is how it looks like - Indefinite loop:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jonne on Slack channel, I was able to identify quickly root cause of issue and find solution.

Solution is to navigate to default storefront under /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts and rename it to name that you specified as defaultshopname during provisioning PaaS environments.

[image]